# Access to controls in cloned tab item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I added in my code copying the first `TabItem` along with all the controls. But now how to reference to these controls to make the appropriate modifications (I mean change label text)? Do I must need make new class and binding ?
I want clone tab item to store data in labels about for example other apps.

XAML code:

```
<TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" x:FieldModifier="public">
   <TabItem x:Name="TabItem1" x:FieldModifier="public" Header="Tab 1">
       <Grid>
           <Label x:Name="Label1" Content="Test 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18"/>
           <Label x:Name="Label2" Content="Test 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18"/>
     
          <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Show Open Dialog" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Click="Button1_Click"/>
      
       </Grid>
   </TabItem>
```

C# code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    mainWindow = this;

    TabItem tab2 = TrycloneElement(TabItem1);
    if (tab2 != null) MainTabControl.Items.Add(tab2);
}

public static T TrycloneElement<T>(T orig)
{
    try
    {
        string s = XamlWriter.Save(orig);

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s);

        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(stringReader, new XmlReaderSettings());
        XmlReaderSettings sx = new XmlReaderSettings();

        object x = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
        return (T)x;
    }
    catch
    {
        return (T)((object)null);
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the _modifications_? What is the intent behind cloning the tab? In other words, what is the real issue that you are trying to solve this way?

Comment: Modification I mean for example change label text.  I want clone tab because in others tabs with same controls I want store data about difference apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the controls by walking the visual tree using `Content`, `Children` or other properties.

```
TabItem tab2 = TrycloneElement(TabItem1);

var grid = (Grid) tab2.Content;
var label1 = (Label) grid.Children[0];
var label2 = (Label) grid.Children[1];
var button = (Button) grid.Children[2];
```

An alternative is to use the [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=net-5.0) and convenience helper methods like described here:

- [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/636383/6181599)

---

Now, these methods work, but you do not need them. You are actually trying to reinvent the wheel. Reusing the same visual structure with different data can be achieved with data templating in a convenient way.

- [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

You can use the same technique for your `TabControl`. I will show you a quick conceptual example that would even comply with the MVVM pattern. This example is **not complete**. It serves as a base for you to learn about an alternative to your current approach. You can of course also make this approach work in code-behind with a few modifications.

Create a data class like below with your application information. Here I assume that it is not editable, otherwise you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to update the user interface on changes.

```
public class AppInfo
{
   public AppInfo(string name, string description)
   {
      Name = name;
      Description = description;
   }

   public string Name { get; }

   public string Description { get; }
}
```

Expose a list of `AppInfo` (or an `ObservableCollection` if the collection is changed at runtime).

```
public List<AppInfo> AppInfos { get; }
```

Initialize the list appropriately and add your items, for example:

```
AppInfos = new List<AppInfo>
{
   new AppInfo("Visual Studio", "A popular IDE."),
   new AppInfo("Calculator", "Does the math for you."),
   new AppInfo("Chrome", "A web browser.")
};
```

The tab control would bind its `ItemsSource` to the `AppInfos`.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding AppInfos}">
```

In order to create a reusable visual representation, create a `DataTemplate` as `ItemTemplate` (this is the tab header) and a `ContentTemplate` (this is the tab content).

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding AppInfos}">
   <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AppInfo}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AppInfo}">
         <Grid>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="10,10,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   FontSize="18"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Description}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="11,44,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   FontSize="18"/>

            <Button Content="Show Open Dialog"
                    IsEnabled="True"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="11,185,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Now, both templates are reused for each item in the `AppInfos` collection. The data template uses bindings to the corresponding properties, which automatically pick up the values for each item.

The `Button` is special here, since it can be clicked to execute an action. This action is probably the same for all items, except that it needs a concrete item to work with. You can encapsulate this logic in commands.

- [MVVM - Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand)

This is another important aspect that can make your life easier, but is beyond the scope of this question. There are lots of tutorials out there. You could expose another property:

```
public ICommand OpenCommand{ get; }
```

The button in XAML binds its `Command` to this property (`RelativeSource` is needed to get the right data context for binding). The `CommandParameter` will pass the current `AppInfo` item to the command. In code, you could then execute your custom logic on this item. No need to know about user interface elements, only data.

**Disclaimer**: I know that this is pretty overwhelming. That is why I provided an immediate (dirty) solution to your issue and an example with links to resources to gradually learn a better way with concrete samples for your exact problem. Once you get used to MVVM, data binding and data templating, you will see how much easier more complex issues can be solved and what the benefits are in terms of maintainability and reuseability.